# Topological space with a countable basis

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

A Topological space $X$ has a countable basis say $(B_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and let $(G_i)_{i \in I}$ be another basis then prove that a countable subcollection of $G_is$ is a basis of $X$.

As $G_is$ form a basis of $X$ hence for every $k$ we have the property that for every $x \in B_k$ there exists a $G_x^k$ such that
$$
x \in G_x^k \subseteq B_k,
$$
then we can write
$$
B_k \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in B_k}G_x^k
$$
and $X$ has a countable basis and so $X$ is Lindelof and so a countable subcollection of $G_x^k$ will cover $B_k$. So Let
$$
B_k \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n^k,
$$
where each of $G_n^k \subseteq B_k$. Now for every $k$ we have a countable collection of $G_is$ and as $k$ varies over $1$ to $\infty$ we get a countable subcollection of $G_is$. Now take any open set in $X$ say $A$ and any $x \in A$. then there exists a $B_{k_0}$ such that $$
x \in B_{k_0} \subseteq A.
$$
Now for this $B_{k_0}$ we have
$$
B_{k_0} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n^{k_0}
$$
and for every $n$, we have $G_n^{k_0} \subseteq B_{k_0}$, and as $x \in B_{k_0}$, hence there is some $G_{n_0}^{k_0}$ such that
$$
x \in G_{n_0}^{k_0} \subseteq B_{k_0} \subseteq A.
$$
Hence the countable subcollection $G_n^k$ forms a basis of $X$.

Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: Yes.  One small point: A countable subcollection of $G^k_x$ covers $B_k$ but not because $X$ is Lindelof, but because $B_k$ is Lindelof because every subspace of $X$ is Lindelof because $X$ has a countable base (basis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (essentially correct) proof can be summarised as follows:

> Lemma: $X$ is second countable so $X$ is hereditarily Lindelöf: for every open cover of an (open) subspace we can find a countable subcover.

(You only mention Lindelöf but this is what you need, and it's strictly stronger).

Then we note that for each $k$ $B_k$ is covered by a subfamily of the $G_i$'s (from being a base), and the lemma says $I(k) \subseteq I$ countable exists so that $$B_k = \bigcup_{i \in I(k)} G_i\tag{1}$$

Then $\mathcal{G} := \{ G_i: i \in \bigcup_k I(k)\}$ is a countable subfamily of $\{G_i\mid i \in I\}$ and as any open set $O$ is a union of some set of $B_k$, $(1)$ ensures that it is a union of some subfamily of $\mathcal{G}$ as well. QED.

This is a bit more succint and easier on notation IMO but is essentially the argument you're using.

Comment: Glad to see you are back. Why did you get suspended?

Comment: @QuantumSpace Answered one "trivial" question too many, one could say..

Comment: I see. I guess they are trying to scare expert topologists away.

Comment: @QuantumSpace rather trying to discourage trivial questions.